# Angular 8: Detect changes to a property

Tags: angular

I have an user entity whose all operations are handled by a single service. I have 2 components - one component displays the related user properties and makes changes to user data, and other component makes changes to certain user properties.

Currently, I have used the service to get the data and perform the operations. But when component changes user data how to detect the change in other component.

Answer (score 0):

Your should use RxJS there in the service. Just use `Subject` type for your data, and `subscribe` to changes in components. It allows components "listen" to the changes in the state of your data in service.

Answer (score 0):

Use [RxJS](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/) to handle changes, let's say you have a user model:

```js
export interface User {
  id: number;
  username: string;
}
```

Then in your service you should handle the model and notify each time you make a change using RxJS Subject:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  private user$: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  user = this.user$.asObservable();

  // Lets say you need to authenticate your user..
  authenticate(user: User) {
    // Authenticate your user here

    // Then notify all your components that the user changed
    this.user$.next(user);
  }
}
```

You can now listen to changes on the User in any of your components:

```js
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  user: Observable<any>;

  constructor(public userService: UserService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.userService.user;
  }
}
```